# jquery validations is not working for dynamic forms that are submitting through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

```
<!--- Edit Popup Start --->
                   <div class="modal fade editpopup" id="edit-pop${subUser.employerId}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                                  <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Edit Your User Details</h4>
                              </div>
                              <c:url var="updateSubUserDetails" value="/employer/recruiters/updateSubUserDetails"/>
                              <form id="updateform${subUser.employerId}" action="${updateSubUserDetails}"  method="post" >
                            <div class="modal-body">
                            <input type="hidden" name="subUserId" value="${subUser.employerId}"/>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="text" id="subUserName${subUser.employerId}" name="subUserName" class="form-control "  value="${subUser.firstName}" placeholder="Edit Sub User Name"/>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="text"  id="subUserEmail${subUser.employerId}" name="subUserEmail" class="form-control "  value="${subUser.emailId}" onchange="checkMail(${subUser.employerId})"    placeholder="Edit Email"/>
                              </div>
                               <span id="avialabilityMessage${subUser.employerId}"></span>  
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="text" id="subUserMobile${subUser.employerId}" name="subUserMobile" class="form-control "  value="${subUser.mobileNumber}"placeholder="Edit Contact No"/>
                              </div>
                                <sec:csrfInput/>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <input type="submit" id="subUserEditButtonID${subUser.employerId}" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" onclick="updateSubUserDetails(${subUser.employerId},event)" value="Update"> 
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <!-- Edit Popup End --->
```

This is my modal, consist of a form for updating user details. These forms are dynamic forms, i am trying to apply jquery validations for this, But those are not working, please assist me.

```
function updateSubUserDetails(id,event) {
          //event.preventDefault();
          $("#updateform"+id).validate({
                rules: {
                    subUserName:{
                        required: true,
                        names: true,
                        maxlength:25
                    },
                    subUserEmail: {
                        required: true,
                        emailid: true,
                        maxlength:255
                    },
                    subUserMobile:{
                        mobile:true,
                    },
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    var data = $("#updateform"+id).serialize();
                    var action=$("#updateform"+id).attr("action");
                            $.ajax({
                            type : "POST",          
                            url : action,
                            data : data,
                                success: function(response){
                                    $('.formFieldError').remove();
                                                if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
                                                    $("#edit-pop"+id).hide();
                                                    var satusMessage = "<span style='color:#41a0f4;font-size:12px'><b>SubUser Details are Updated Successfully</b></span>";
                                                    $('#statusMessageSpan').html(satusMessage);
                                                 } if(response.status == "ERROR"){
                                                        for(var key in response.errorsMap){
                                                            var array=response.errorsMap[key];
                                                            for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
                                                                {
                                                                 $("<p class=\"formFieldError\"  style='margin:0;color:indianred' id=\""+key+"Id\">"+array[i]+"</p>").insertAfter("#"+(key+id));
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                             }
                                        });

                            getSubUsersAjax();
                     }
            });

      }
```

The following script is ajax script

```
function getSubUsersAjax(){
       var millisecondsToWait = 50;
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",           
                url : "viewSubUsersAjax",
                success: function(data){
                tableReplace(data);
                    }
             });
        }, millisecondsToWait);
 }
```

Comment: You can call your validation function after ajax success response.

Comment: i don't want to submit my form with out validation, success function will call after the successful submission of a form.

Comment: Could you please tell us exactly what do you mean by "not working" Are you getting an error in the console? Are the validations not running at all? A minimal example with the behavior you  are having will give you more good answers than anything else, from the code you posted there is no way to see the problem.

Comment: @SuryaMovva - I mean to your validation function should call after your dynamically form render.

Comment: Jquery validation is not applying to that form,form is rendering .I am submitting the form through ajax using above script.If I comment event.preventDefault request is going to server.But before request is going to server I want to validate that data inside form,Those validations are not calling at all.